# How do I RDP from windows into Ubuntu with i3-wm?

Tags: 20.04, xorg, xrdp, i3-wm, rdp

I installed regular Ubuntu 20.04
I then installed i3

On the local computer I have a choice on login of ubuntu or i3 and logging into i3 works beautifully!

I installed XRDP and I am RDP'ing from a Windows 10 computer.
I can login using Xorg but I get the Ubuntu windows manager and not i3.

What is the correct way to setup the config so my RDP session goes to i3 and works?